# What does Hs before a proper name stand for?

Tags: meaning

Swiss ancestry names ie. "Hs George or Hs Jakob"

Comment: I can't seem to find any examples with google (except this thread), could you [edit] the question to include a link to some text where it's used? (Excepting Hs as an abbreviation for Hans).

Comment: I don't see why this is getting close votes for "research" reasons -- I can't find any meaning of the term that would seem to fit.

Comment: @HotLicks But you've looked. Susan, if you have looked for "Hs", your question should include that research: it means other people don't have to repeat it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=q0TJqK5G_ZIC&pg=PA264&lpg=PA264&dq=Verk%C3%BCndung+german+genealogy&source=bl&ots=cTyTdr5RQV&sig=nxA87yWxVtmXtAF0zxsos1qLO-Y&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DQaUVb7WM4LRoASKiJG4Dg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAw#v=snippet&q=Hs&f=false), it’s an abbreviation for the masculine given name Hans.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in table at the end of the page at [familysearch.org](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Switzerland_Names,_Personal), it is an abbreviation for ***Hans*** used by the Swiss geneologist [Julius Billeter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Billeter) in his research.

```
Hs Conr = Hans K(C)onrad.  
Hs Jb = Hans Jacob.  
Hs Rud. = Hans Rudolf.
```